# Smarty: Disabling include errors

Tags: php, smarty

I have few templates included in index. Index is responsible for outputing every page in site.
I include them like this:

```
{include file="`$show`_contentleft.tpl"}
```

For some reason any of those templates are not needed.

So if i don't have a template, there is smarty error:

```
Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file
```

It should be skipped. How can i disable this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can simply remove those lines or comment them using:

```
{*  {include file="`$show`_contentleft.tpl"}  *}
```

**EDIT**

After explanation it could be done using `file_exists` but you need to include also directory structure.

For example in my index.php I have:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir('templates');
```

so in my template I have to use:

```
{if file_exists("templates/`$show`_contentleft.tpl")}
    {include file="`$show`_contentleft.tpl"}
{/if}
```

If I don't use correct path in `file_exists`, `file_exists` never find this file so never include this file regardless of `$show` value.

Comment: Well, i didn't meant this. I have no template files in template folder. For example i have about_contentleft.tpl, but don't have services_contentleft.tpl, where "about" and "services" are $show variable. The point is skip them or avoid. Somehow {if fileexist()} doesn't works with $template_dir correctly set. I saw in other project this including doesn't throws an error. I'd wanted to do the same...